# git sha cannot be found: bad object

Tags: git

Here is the problem:
Another Dev pushed something. A SHA was created and can be found in cgit (commit/?id=$LOST_SHA). In my local working copy I'm up-to-date but

```
git log --all $LOST_SHA
```

says "fatal: bad object $LOST_SHA". Any idea how this could happen? 
The dev said he removed some pushed tags. But I'm not sure if this was all, he did.

```
git fsck
```

gives

```
13 dangling commits
16 dangling blobs
```

but non of them has the sha I'm looking for.

Can it be, that the Dev created a remote branch and deleted it after a while. Cgit did a fetch while the branch existed and I did my fetch after it was already deleted? So I did not even see, that there ever was a branch at all.

Thanks

Comment: Please run `git fsck` and add the results to your question.

Comment: cgit doesn't fetch, but yes, it's certainly possible that pushing a branch and then removing that branch would have the effect you see. Is this a problem? How did you get this SHA1? Did cgit show that commit in the history of any particular branch?